# Inserting an Excel OLE objects in another Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I use this code to add an OLE object in an Excel worksheet:

```
Set OLE = wsAttachment.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=sDateinameMitPfad, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=0, IconFileName:=sDateinameMitPfad)
```

This works when I insert files like jpg, png or docx
When I try to add another xlsx file I get a warning:

> Caution! Parts of your document may contain personal information that
>   can not be removed from the document examination.

(Sorry, Google translate) The original german messagebox shows:

> Vorsicht! Teile Ihres Dokuments enthalten möglicherweise persönliche
>   Informationen, die von der Dokumentprüfung nicht entfernt werden
>   können.

I know that this behaviour can be stopped in the trust center, which is not an option (users can not change their trust center settings).

How do I add an external xlsx file without this warning?